# MVC, работа с моделью

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, mvc, pdo

Дело было вечером, делать было нечего.
Для расширения кругозора решил написать мини-фреймворк на чистом PHP.
Стал вопрос с работой с моделями.
Хочу связать модель с базой данных.
Как это внедрить? Работаю с PDO
Нужно именно сопоставить таблицу с обьявленным columnMap в моделе.
Что бы можно было обращатся типа:

```
$model->id_model = '4';
$model->save();
```

Comment: Прежде чем задавать общий вопрос, вы смотрели на другие фреймы, как это реализовано там?

Comment: Я работал с Phalcon, где все исходники написаны на Zephir, и пока сложно воспринимать этой смежный язык.

Comment: $model->save() - это Active Records, который является антипаттерном. Лучше сделать сперва DataMapper (http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Structural/DataMapper/README.html), а затем UnitOfWork (http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/unit-of-work.html)

Comment: Поздравляю кадет, вы мыслите в классическом направлении :) Но, вынужден расстроить, магии не будет - простые ORM не пишутся на коленке. И еще - придется разбираться самому, прошу ознакомиться https://github.com/noetix/Simple-ORM

Comment: Я и не жду какого-либо готового решение, просто банально загуглить не знаю как)

Comment: @AlexShawnee все что написано больше 2 лет назад можно списывать в утиль. слишком много косяков плюс антипаттерн. Я вот мечтаю написать учебный датамаппер, но знаний пока не хватает

Comment: @DaemonHK в нескольких сотнях тысяч строк разобраться не так просто вообще-то.

Comment: @Ипатьев сотни тысяч строк отвечают не только за модели))

Comment: @Ипатьев в таком случае вы будете долго возиться, тем более что сам php уже дедушка и по вашим же соображениям должен быть "списан в утиль". Некоторые вещи проще и быстрее реализовать на node, python, кои собственно вам и рекомендую, npm в помощь - там код на любой вкус и любой же свежести. Вопрос состоял в дата байдинге - вам привели ссылки на материалы, дали наставления, думаю вопрос закрыт? :)

Comment: @Ипатьев https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.19/framework/base/CModel.php https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.19/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/form.model

Общие принципы работы, надеюсь сообразите как найти?

Comment: @DaemonHK как уже выше сказали, AR - это антипаттерн. Зачем вот это вот все, что по ссылке, в классе "Товар" или "Заказ" - загадка.

Comment: @Ипатьев, зачем вообще тогда наследование и абстрактные классы?)) Тогда уже легче под каждую сущность писать свою обработку.

Comment: @DaemonHK наследование совсем для другого. К примеру, класс маппера может наследовать базовые CRUD методы от абстрактного маппера. AR нарушает single responsibility principle, связывая сам объект и его маппинг.